# How can I allow a child class to call one of multiple base constructors with the same signatures?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, signature

I have a parent class in C# that contains several constructors. Some of them have the same signatures, like so.

```
public MyClass()
{
    //Do something
}

public MyClass()
{
    //Do something else
}
```

How can I allow a child class to choose only one of these constructors to use as a base?

Comment: How can you even compile such a base class in c#?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Well, that's kind of the problem. Not only do I want a child class to choose a specific base constructor, but I want to allow the parent class to have multiple constructors with the same signature in the first place. None of them actually require any parameters to accomplish their jobs.

Comment: Why exactly do you want constructors with the same signature that do different things? It almost sounds as if they might be different classes in the one inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Your code results in a compiler error: "error CS0111: Type 'MyClass' already defines a member called 'MyClass' with the same parameter types"

Comment: You're effectively asking for a completely different language, rather than C#. You cannot have multiple members of the same "name" with identical signatures

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So if I have two constructors, neither of which require parameters to accomplish what they need to, how can I implement them? I had briefly considered providing one of them with a parameter (which it wouldn't use) just to distinguish between them, but I expected that such logic was discouraged in the world of programming. i.e. I would have `MyClass(int I)` and `MyClass()`.

Comment: In that case I would say you have a fundamental software design problem.

Comment: What is it that you want the two (base) constructors to do?

Comment: If you have two "parameterless" constructors, and you want your callers to be able to distinguish between which one should be called, are you not in reality describing a constructor with a single `bool` parameter (which would be used)?

Comment: @Ben, please see my answer below. What you are trying to achieve is impossible. Why do you want to go this way? If you explain the reasons behind I might be able to provide a better suggestion.

Comment: @Anton Right, for a bit of added clarity, the parent class is inheriting from another grandparent class. One of the parent's constructors should call the grandparent's constructor, while the other one shouldn't. In both cases, the parent's constructors don't require parameters.

Comment: @Ben, interesting, however I am not sure if you realize that parent (in your case the grandparent) constructor is called always. There is no way to avoid it. A constructor always calls its parent constructor even if you do not specify the `base()` command. In such case the default parameterless constructor of the parent class is called.

Comment: @Anton Well, the grandparent has both a blank constructor and one that requires a string to be passed to it. One of the parent's constructors passes the string and the other doesn't.

Comment: @Ben, ok, in such case please see my updated answer. I hope this is actually what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# it is not possible to have multiple constructors with the same signature within a single class. Why don't you simply implement multiple protected methods - each method with its own specific name and then call the desired method from the child's constructor? Something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    protected Foo()
    {
        // Do something
    }

    protected Bar()
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}

public class MyChildClass : MyClass
{
    public MyChildClass(int x)
    {
        if(x > 0)
        {
            Foo();
        }
        else
        {
            Bar();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Update

Based on the additional information provided in the comments I am adding one more possible solution that may be a better fit for your case:

```
public class MyGrandClass
{
    public MyGrandClass(string name)
    {
        // Do something with the name.
    }

    public MyGrandClass()
    {
        // Do something else.
    }
}

public class MyClass : MyGrandClass
{
    public MyClass(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
    }
}

public class MyChildClass : MyClass
{
    public MyChildClass(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }

    public MyChildClass()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's impossible that you could define more than a constructor with the same parameters (or no parameters at all...), **you can define a single constructor with optional parameters**:

```
public class A
{
    public A(string x = null, int y = -1)
    {
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B(string x) : base(x)
    {
    }
}

public class B2 : A
{
    public B(int y) : base(y)
    {
    }
}

// You can even inherit A and don't call the A's constructor
// because all parameters are optional
public class B3 : A
{
}
```